# Angular interpolation on element ID leads to addition of trailing space to attribute value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've been using Angular directives and have encountered a slightly weird issue where a trailing space is appended to element IDs when I try to autogenerate them.

I have two directives that are nested. In my outer directive template I have the following code snippet:

```
<div combobox
     id="{{questionId}}-list-id"
     name="{{questionId}}-list"
     model="model"
     options="options"></div>
```

Then, in my inner combobox directive I have the following:

```
<select
    name="{{name}}"
    required
    id="{{id}}"
    ng-model="model">
    <option
        ng-repeat="option in options"
        value="{{option.value}}"
        ng-selected="model === option.value">{{option.caption}}</option>
</select>
```

Let's say I set questionId to "own-or-rent", I'd expect the `id` attribute on my select element to have the value "own-or-rent-list-id", but in fact it has the value "own-or-rent-list-id ".

I've also tried using `ng-attr-id="{{questionId + '-list-id'}}"`, instead of setting the value of `id` directly but the result is the same. I've also experimented with different values for the generated ID but to no avail.

How can I get rid of this trailing space? It's causing us problems with our tests and, when we need to start customising individual questions, is also going to play havoc with them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Bart

**Edit**

This is with Angular 1.2.26 (because we have to maintain compatibility with IE8).

Here's the JS for my outer directive:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("question")
        .directive("comboboxQuestion", function () {
            return {
                scope: {
                    questionId: "@",
                    questionText: "@",
                    options: "=",
                    model: "="
                },
                restrict: "AE",
                replace: "true",
                transclude: true,
                templateUrl: "/content/pages/directives/combobox-question.html"
            };
        });
}());
```

And here's the JS for my inner combobox directive:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("question")
        .directive("combobox", function () {
            return {
                scope: {
                    name: "@",
                    id: "@",
                    options: "=",
                    model: "="
                },
                restrict: "AE",
                replace: "true",
                transclude: true,
                templateUrl: "/content/pages/directives/combobox.html"
            };
        });
}());
```

Comment: AngularJS version? Can you show the combobox directive code?

Comment: @tasseKATT Thanks - just posted above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I've figured this out. The problem is due to a naming collision.

I'm using attributes called `id` and `name` in my directive. What's happening is that the value of these attributes is being concatenated with whatever values the underlying `id` and `name` and value attributes on the `select` element have regardless of whether or not I set them on the `select` element as within my directive's markup template.

This is illustrated if I set the values of these attributes to something fixed on the `select`, like 'hello'. If, for example, I do this for `id` I end up with a value of the form "generated-id hello". Note the space in the middle between the concatenated values.

To fix it I've added a three letter vendor prefix to my `id` and `name` attributes to give me `ctmId` and `ctmName` in the directive JS (and any interpolations where they're used), and `ctm-id` and `ctm-name` in the markup.

It's not the nicest, but not the end of the world, and really my own lookout in the first place for using attribute names that collide with attributes that can legitimately appear on a `div` anyway.

Hope this comes in useful for somebody else too!